# Android garbage collector working hard in my application

Tags: android, garbage-collection

my application has a Service with Thread which runs on the background and listen for communication from a remote server.
while the thread is running i see in my LogCat a lot of dalvikvm actions.
is it ok ? or maybe it is some sorted of memory leak:

this is my Thread run():

```
@Override
public void run() {
    startKeepAliveTimer();  
    try {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
            if (socket != null)
            {
                Log.i("ServerConnection", "Server connection opened");
                this.app.setConnectedToServer(true);
                serverManager.loginToServer();
            }
            else
                app.setConnectedToServer(false);

            while (app.isConnectedToServer()) 
            {
                app.getFacebookManager().refreshAccessToken();                      
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
                String input;
                input = in.readLine();
                if (input != null)
                {
                    lastOnline = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    input = input.trim();
                    input = app.decrypt(input);
                    Log.e("Server Reponse", input);                 
                    serverManager.processData(app.convertToJSONObject(input));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ServerConnection", e.toString());
        }           

        Log.i("ServerConnection", "Server connection closed");
}
```

this is my StackTrace:

```
paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:36.862: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1367K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+2ms
            11-09 15:42:36.892: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1390K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:36.902: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:36.932: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:36.952: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:36.972: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:36.992: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 12ms
            11-09 15:42:37.022: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 2ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.032: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:37.052: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 33% free 10644K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.072: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1406K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:37.092: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1245K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:37.112: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:37.132: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 33% free 10644K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.152: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1406K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:37.182: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1245K, 25% free 12018K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.212: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3208K, 33% free 10664K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:37.232: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1426K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 11ms
            11-09 15:42:37.252: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:37.272: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:37.302: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 3ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:37.312: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:37.332: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:37.362: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 7ms
            11-09 15:42:37.402: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1360K, 33% free 10667K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.432: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1299K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.452: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 13ms
            11-09 15:42:37.472: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.492: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 12ms
            11-09 15:42:37.512: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:37.532: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:37.552: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.572: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:37.622: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1266K, 32% free 10761K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.642: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1562K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 13ms
            11-09 15:42:37.672: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1367K, 33% free 10653K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.692: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 10ms
            11-09 15:42:37.712: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.722: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:37.752: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 32% free 10758K/15815K, paused 2ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.762: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1559K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 11ms
            11-09 15:42:37.792: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1367K, 33% free 10653K/15815K, paused 2ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.812: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 10ms
            11-09 15:42:37.832: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.852: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 10ms
            11-09 15:42:37.872: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 33% free 10644K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.882: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1406K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:37.912: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1245K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:37.932: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:37.962: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 0ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:37.972: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 10ms
            11-09 15:42:38.002: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 32% free 10758K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.012: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1559K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 12ms
            11-09 15:42:38.042: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1367K, 33% free 10653K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.062: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:38.092: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.112: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1293K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:38.132: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 13ms
            11-09 15:42:38.162: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 2ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.182: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 11ms
            11-09 15:42:38.202: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:38.222: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:38.242: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.262: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 7ms
            11-09 15:42:38.272: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 33% free 10644K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.292: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1406K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:38.322: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10653K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.342: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 7ms
            11-09 15:42:38.362: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.382: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:38.402: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 33% free 10644K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:38.412: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1406K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:38.442: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1245K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.462: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:38.492: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 25% free 12019K/15815K, paused 1ms+2ms
            11-09 15:42:38.522: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3103K, 32% free 10769K/15815K, paused 1ms+2ms
            11-09 15:42:38.532: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1570K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:38.552: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1270K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.572: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 7ms
            11-09 15:42:38.592: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.622: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1293K, 32% free 10758K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.632: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1559K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 11ms
            11-09 15:42:38.662: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1246K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.682: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 13ms
            11-09 15:42:38.702: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.722: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 11ms
            11-09 15:42:38.742: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.762: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 10ms
            11-09 15:42:38.782: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 33% free 10644K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.802: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1406K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 10ms
            11-09 15:42:38.822: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1245K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.842: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:38.872: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 24% free 12027K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.902: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3208K, 33% free 10672K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:38.912: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1450K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:38.942: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10653K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:38.962: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 7ms
            11-09 15:42:38.982: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.002: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 10ms
            11-09 15:42:39.022: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.042: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:39.072: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.092: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1390K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.112: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:39.132: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.152: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:39.172: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+0ms
            11-09 15:42:39.192: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 11ms
            11-09 15:42:39.212: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.232: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:39.252: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.272: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 10ms
            11-09 15:42:39.302: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 2ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.322: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 11ms
            11-09 15:42:39.342: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 2ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.362: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 11ms
            11-09 15:42:39.382: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.402: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 11ms
            11-09 15:42:39.432: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 32% free 10758K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.442: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1559K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 11ms
            11-09 15:42:39.472: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1246K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.492: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 10ms
            11-09 15:42:39.522: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.532: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 8ms
            11-09 15:42:39.562: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 2ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.572: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:39.602: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.612: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 12ms
            11-09 15:42:39.642: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.652: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 9ms
            11-09 15:42:39.682: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 32% free 10758K/15815K, paused 1ms+2ms
            11-09 15:42:39.692: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1559K, 33% free 10629K/15815K, paused 10ms
            11-09 15:42:39.722: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1246K, 33% free 10652K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
            11-09 15:42:39.742: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 33% free 10637K/15815K, paused 12ms
            11-09 15:42:39.762: D/dalvikvm(3806): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1366K, 33% free 10661K/15815K, paused 1ms+1ms
```

***UPDATE:***
after removing all the "new" elemnts from inside the loop, i've used the DDMS allocation trackor and found that i have lots of allocation in the input=in.readLine(); something with wrap() function inside the InputStream object... how can it be ? and what to do

Comment: Could you post some of your service code to better understand what happens ?

Comment: you're right - i've added it

Comment: Maybe you can try to instantiate your `BufferedReader` outside the `while loop` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't be that much of a problem - after all, it's not an error but the GC doing its job.

However, in this case, a lot of memory is being freed every second (And since the state of the heap remains the same (Allocated - Free), it also mean this memory is being allocated every second.This will intensify battery consumption and will cause lags in your app.

Like others suggested, try to instantiate objects outside of the `while`, instead of creating and deleting them every loop. For example, change your loop to:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
while (app.isConnectedToServer()) 
        {
            app.getFacebookManager().refreshAccessToken();                      
            String input;
            input = in.readLine();
            if (input != null)
            {
                lastOnline = System.currentTimeMillis();
                input = input.trim();
                input = app.decrypt(input);
                Log.e("Server Reponse", input);                 
                serverManager.processData(app.convertToJSONObject(input));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collector activates when you have objects that were created and are not used anymore.

That means, any `new` keyword on your `run()` (including methods called inside the run that also have this keyword) will be collecting  will be garbage collected later.

Some stuff is necessary to be re-created all the time (for example, the Streams) but some might be kept on the memory (for example, the socket, if its lifecycle is properly handled). You can dig inside the `startKeepAliveTimer();` ; `serverManager.processData(app.convertToJSONObject(input));` and other methods to check if they're not creating every time stuff that could be kept through the life of your service.

But despite all that... it seems to me that the GC is doing is job nicely, and it's always collecting and the memory usage is fairly stable, I wouldn't worry too much.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Budius. GC is left to android os. If your experiencing too much memory consumption in your application, try modifying it. Use a MAT analyzer to find memory leaks.
This video is about memory management. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. . So if you look at the video you should be able to get rid of the memory leaks.

Also if you have a long running operation make sure you run them on threads. I suggest you to use asynctask. Running long running operation on UI Thread also causes memory leaks.

Comment: after removing all the "new" elemnts from inside the loop, i've used the DDMS allocation trackor and found that i have lots of allocation in the input=in.readLine(); something with wrap() function inside the InputStream object... how can it be ? and what to do